# How to convert JSON rows to columns

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pivot, reshape

I have a JSON data structure that is row-based:

```
rows = [
    {'name': 'tim', 'age': 113}, 
    {'name': 'tess', 'age': 111},
]
```

that I would like to convert to column-based data:

```
columns = {
    'name': ['tim', 'tess'],
    'age': [113, 111],
}
```

What is the most readable way to do this if there are lots of rows and columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

rows = [
    {'name': 'tim', 'age': 113}, 
    {'name': 'tess', 'age': 111},
]

d = defaultdict(list)
for r in rows:
    for k, v in r.items():
        d[k].append(v)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'name': ['tim', 'tess'], 'age': [113, 111]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
from collections import defaultdict
x = defaultdict(list)
for item in rows:
    for key, value in item.items():
        x[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_rows={'name':[],'age':[]}
for row in rows:
    new_rows['name'].append(row['name'])
    new_rows['age'].append(row['age'])
```

Here, I am creating a new dict i.e 'new_rows'. Now iterating over the elements of 'rows', appending the values of each dict element to 'new_rows' keys

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with:

```py
columns = {k: [d[k] for d in rows] for k in rows[0]}
```

Explanation:

Iterate over the keys of the first row (`rows[0]`), and wrap that in a dictionary
comprehension. The dictionary comprehension then goes and gets the values for
each key from each row.

So the whole thing is a bunch of list comprehensions (one for each key) that iterate over the rows, wrapped
in a dictionary comprehension that iterates over the keys of the first row.